# In iphone, how to check whether internet is there from the app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When my app starts, I want to check whether the net connection is avaliable or not. And if not I want to show an alert message. How can I check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Apple's Reachability example: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html. It will show you everything you need on how to detect the network state of the device.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpfull and I succeeded in what I was trying to do.